# CSS only lightbox solution

Tags: css

I am working on a CSS only lightbox solution for my project. I've googled it but so far found only partial solutions.

I am looking for these features:

- display content of any width and any height (no fixed height/width)
- center verticaly and horizontaly
- display scrollbars if content width and/or height overflows lightbox boundary due to viewport dimensions.

So far I have this:

```
.lb-overlay {
    text-align: center;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.lb-overlay:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.lb-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    z-index: 10001;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.lb-content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 2em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lb-close {
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
    background-color: #d00000;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lb-close:hover { background-color: #f00000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TomasReichmann/F4D5u/1/

problems:

- vertical scrollbar doesn't appear
- horizontal scrollbar works only in chrome

Ideally, I am looking for compatibility with modern browsers and IE8+, but I can live with IE9+

Can you guys help?

Comment: Working with position:relative and overflow:auto is always a bit tricky. Making the parent `position:relative;` and the child `position:absolute;` You haven't set this now.

Comment: `.lb-content` does not have any width/height restrictions, so using `overflow:auto` on it of course does not have the desired effect. `.lb-wrap` _has_, so using overflow on that will give you a scrollbar when the content _in_ `.lb-content` is to large. (But that then will make `.lb-close` scroll with the content, so you will most likely need an additional wrapper.)

Comment: @KeesSonnema I don't understand. I have either position:fixed or position:relative on all elements.

Comment: @CBroe: where do you think that wrapper would have to go? Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TomasReichmann/F4D5u/2

Comment: @Tom I think he wants the close button to not scroll with the content.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of the unnecessary sizing models
2. Full-size the overlay as width: 100%; height: 100%;
3. Use margin: auto and position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; to center align the wrap within the overlay both vertically and horizontally
4. Use width and height instead of max-width and max-height
5. Use padding on wrap to control the border around the content
6. Use overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%; in content

Summed up: http://jsfiddle.net/F4D5u/8/

Complete style code:

```
.lb-overlay {
    background: #c0c0c0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.lb-wrap {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 70%; height: 70%;
    padding : 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.lb-content {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

.lb-close {
    position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px;
    background-color: #d00000;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.lb-close:hover { background-color: #f00000; }
```

Comment: Great suggestion, I have already tried that, but as you can see, the close button now scrolls with content and the scrollbar is outside of content padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/TomasReichmann/F4D5u/2/

Comment: Re-did my answer entirely ;)

Comment: First of all, another cool solution. Totally usable for number of scenarios. The scrollbars work great. I tested it with an image and even the horizontal bar works as expected. Unfortunately, some of the features are missing:


 - Vertical centering is somewhat off center :-D
 - The wrapper no longer wraps around the content, so fixed width content will be floating inside huge container (depending on the viewport size)
 - It breaks when the viewport height is small enough (i could ignore that. Only place this would matter would be on smartphone while landscape)

Comment: This is my final answer. There is no way to make a perfectly flexible and auto-resizing container that somehow aligns itself to the center. I've fixed the centering portion, but the width and height have to remain fixed for that. The deeper question is how would a container know what the appropriate width and height is for a block of text within it? How it is wrapped is quite subjective. I would assume that the content is loaded dynamically via script, so it would make sense that there are a couple of predefined dimensions that you can size the wrap programmatically according to the content.

Comment: The Fiddle from my question description contains a div with set width for the text. Basicly I want it to behave the same way for example colorbox does. They calculate dimensions of the content that is about to be loaded into the box and center it. This is what my original solution does via display: inline-block, which wraps around the contents same way as float: left, or position: absolute do by default. The lightbox can recieve an object of any width/height and should shrink around it as colorbox does. Your solution while fine, doesn't really solve that. So I cant mark it as solution, sorry.

Comment: That being said, I SO apreciate your effort and time you spent on that. I believe your answer will help at least some people who stumble upon it :-)